# Laravel 4 link_to with user id generates NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, url, laravel

UsersController:

```
protected $user;

public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function show($id)
{
    $user = $this->user->find($id);
    return View::make('users.show')->with('user',$user);
}
```

Model:

```
protected $table = 'users';
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('users','UsersController');
```

Code that creates the link in views/users: "index.blade.php":

```
{{ link_to("/users/show/{$user->id}", ($user->first_name), $secure = null) }}
```

Object code in the page being linked to, in views/users: "show.blade.php":

```
$user->{field} ...
```

where my code puts in the field names, not enclosed in {} of course.

The link generates this URL:

```
https://.../users/show/{#}
```

where {#} is the user id associated with the link, e.g. .../users/show/7

Clicking the link in users/index generates a NotFoundHttpException.

I know this is really basic stuff, but I am going crazy trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm not sure I understand what the "$secure = null" is for, but I'm following the Laravel docs; it makes no difference if it's there or not, still getting the Not Found exception if I remove it. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a [resource controller](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) , which maps to:

```
Verb    Path                   Action   Route Name
GET     /resource/{resource}    show    resource.show
```

You can create a link to the named route:

```
{{link_to_route('users.show', $user->first_name, $user->id)}}
```

or

```
{{link_to('users/'.$user->id, $user->first_name)}}
```

Comment: Thank you Damien -- that works! But now that the routing is working, I have a security question. I notice that if I change the number of the user id in the URL in the browser's nav window and reload the page, that it will reload with the user corresponding to the changed id. Isn't that a security risk, e.g. if the user is only supposed to have access to defined id's? Adding back "$secure = null" doesn't change that; what is the purpose of that in the Laravel documentation? Short of using a form with a hidden field, is there a way of doing this without the id in the URL? Thanks again.

Comment: `$secure` refers to the usage/creation of an https link. Your issue has nothing to do with security. If you want to check the correctness of the `$id` you need a validation logic in your code (ex, check if the ID correspondes to the logged user ID, or if the ID exists, or anything else, it depends on *your* logic ;)

Comment: Thanks. You've been very helpful, I really appreciate it. -Steve

Comment: Glad to have helped! I see you're new to StackOverflow;if an answers is helpful / solves your problem please consider upvoting/accepting it (you can mark an answer as accepted by checking the thick mark under the vote count), so that future reader will see at once the solution

Comment: Again, thx. I did accept the answer, but the system wouldn't accept my vote since I don't have enough points yet.